# How to get the number of reservations for each customer for the below table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables and i just want to know how to get the number of reservations for each customer for the below table.

Thank you for your support.

[image: How to get the number of reservations for each customer for the below table.]

Comment: What code have you tried?  We are happy to help you troubleshoot, but we aren't a code writing service.  We expect that you *at least* make an effort to answer the question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `group by` query:

```
select customer.customer_id from customer, count(customer.customer_id) as reservation_count
from customer
left join reservation on reservation.customer_customer_id = customer.customer_id
group by customer.customer_id
```

In this case a `left join` is used to include customers that don't have any reservations and should have a `reservation_count` of 0. Customers with reservations will have a `reservation_count` greater than 0.

Comment: Thank you for your collaboration
I tried to use this but there is an error after as 

SELECT
  customer.customer_id
FROM
  customer,
  COUNT * AS reservation_count

LEFT JOIN
  reservation ON reservation.customer_customer_id = customer.customer_id
GROUP BY
  customer.customer_id

Comment: I also tryed to remove the * after COUNT but doesn't work

Comment: I tryed this code also BUT still also 

SELECT
  customer.customer_id
FROM
  customer
JOIN
  reservation,
  COUNT AS reservation_count
LEFT JOIN
  reservation ON reservation.customer_customer_id = customer.customer_id
WHERE
  reservation.customer_customer_id = customer.customer_id
GROUP BY
  customer.customer_id




here is the error 

#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'reservation'

Comment: I think it should be reservation table because we need the total number of reservation for each customer. what is your advise

Comment: `WHERE` isn't needed in your query.

Comment: still same issue after i remove it

Comment: I solve it under this solution 
SELECT name, customer.customer_id, COUNT(*) AS number_of_orders FROM customer, reservation WHERE customer.customer_id = reservation.customer_customer_id GROUP BY name ORDER BY customer.customer_id